# How to ensure that a changeset can pattern match Ecto Repo.Insert/1's private functions?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm using Ecto for the first time making a Phoenix blog, and having issues with Repo.insert/1. The specific error I'm getting is:

```
no function clause matching in Ecto.Repo.Schema.metadata/1
```

I've been playing around with IEx.pry and see that the changeset I pass to Repo.Insert is valid (valid: true), and contains the changes I want (changes: %{content: "bar", title: "foo"}). However, I see that Repo.Schema.metadata/1 requires context and source and I'm not sure whether Repo.insert or Repo.do_insert are able to obtain & add that. Nor do I know how to inspect the state of variables within the Ecto private functions.

My controller code:

```
def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params}) do
  changeset = Post.changeset(%Post{}, post_params)
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do #this line blows up
    {:ok, post} ->
```

My model code:

```
defstruct [:id, :title, :date, :content, :active]

schema "posts" do
  field :title, :string
  field :date, Ecto.DateTime
  field :content, :string #is text in migration
  field :active, :boolean, default: false

  timestamps
end

@required_fields ~w(title content)
@optional_fields ~w(date)

def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is likely the `defstruct [:id, :title, :date, :content, :active]` line. You are overriding the struct generated by the `schema` macro with your own.

Delete it and your code should work.